# displaying iframe once image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, iframe

I am trying to inject iframe after image is clicked, I can make it to work without injecting so it appear at the start of the page but not when image is pressed. How do I do that?

View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Best programmer ever')
@section('content')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/template.js') !!}"></script>
@endsection
        @section('template')
        <div class= "template_class">
            @foreach ($templates as $template)

        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
        </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
            <iframe class="content-link" src="{{ asset($template->file )}}">
@show
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $('.content-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.template_class').load(this.src);

   });
});
```

Comment: `this` is not allowed in click handler function, so try to save reference to `this` like, `var self = this` and then use `self` reference inside of your callback

Comment: @TelmanAgababov nothing wrong with current use of `this`. It references element that event occurred on

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Possible there is another reason

Comment: You need to put back the links you used to have and change out `load()` to set the iframe src instead. See http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: So how would I put iframe src inside load ()? Amy example I can have, not necessarily on my code